# How to do update operation for cascading Textbox in mvc5?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I want to know how to do update operation in cascading textbox in MVC5.

[image]

In this I have two fields called **CustomerName** and **ContactPerson**.  These two fields are cascading textbox fields. That is if i type and select the CustomerName the CustomerName related ContactPerson will load automatically in contact person drop down. This is is working fine

Now what i want is how to pass the value from db to contact person dropdown in edit mode . I passed the value to CustomerName textbox in edit mode. Its working fine but i cant able to pass the value to contact person dropdown

**Cascadind textbox coding**

**My Model (VisitorsViewModel)**

```
public Nullable<System.Guid> CustomerID { get; set; }
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.Guid> CustomerContactID { get; set; }
```

**My ViewCode**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.CustomerName, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CustomerName, new { @class = "form-control required" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.CustomerID)


@Html.Label("Contact Person", new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerContactID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text", id = "CustomerContactID" })
```

**My J-query Code**

```
 <link href="~/Areas/Sales/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Areas/Sales/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Areas/Sales/Scripts/jquery-ui.1.10.4min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $('#CustomerName').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetVisitCustomer", "VisitorsForm")',
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: {
                        Areas: 'Sales',
                        term: request.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (val, item) {
                            return {
                                label: val.Name,
                                value: val.Name,
                                customerId: val.ID
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#CustomerID").val(ui.item.customerId);
                $('#CustomerContactID').empty();
                $.ajax(
                        '@Url.Action("GetContactPersobByCustomerId", "VisitorsForm", new { Area = "Sales" })', {
                            type: "POST",
                            datatype: "Json",
                            data: { CustomerID: $('#CustomerID').val() },
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#CustomerContactID').append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
                                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                                $('#CustomerContactID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerContactID + '">' + value.ContactReference + '</option>');
                                });
                            }
                        });
                       }
                    });
```

**My Controller Code to load CustomerName and ContactPerson**

```
 public JsonResult GetVisitCustomer(string Areas, string term = "")
  {
        var objCustomerlist = db.Customers.Where(c => c.IsDeleted == false)
                        .Where(c => c.DisplayName.ToUpper()
                        .Contains(term.ToUpper()))
                        .Select(c => new { Name = c.DisplayName, ID = c.CustomerID })
                        .Distinct().ToList();
        return Json(objCustomerlist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }

public JsonResult GetContactPersobByCustomerId(string customerId)
  {
          Guid Id = Guid.Parse(customerId);
         var customercontacts = (from a in db.CustomerContacts where a.CustomerID == Id select a);
          return Json(customercontacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

**Edit Code**

**Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
 {
    WafeERP_NEWEntities db = new WafeERP_NEWEntities();
    VisitorsViewModel objvisitorsviewmodel = new VisitorsViewModel();
    View_VisitorsForm objviewvisitorsForm = db.View_VisitorsForm.Find(id);

        ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "DisplayName", objviewvisitorsForm.EmployeeID);
        ViewBag.POVisitID = new SelectList(db.POVisits, "POVisitID", "POVisit1", objviewvisitorsForm.POVisitID);
        ViewBag.ItemID = new SelectList(db.Items, "ItemID", "DisplayName", objviewvisitorsForm.ItemID);


     objvisitorsviewmodel.VisitingID = objviewvisitorsForm.VisitingID;
     objvisitorsviewmodel.Date = objviewvisitorsForm.VisitingDate;
     objvisitorsviewmodel.CustomerID = objviewvisitorsForm.CustomerID;
     objvisitorsviewmodel.CustomerName = objviewvisitorsForm.CustomerName;
     return View(objvisitorsviewmodel);
    }
```

Here I passed the **CustomerName** value to the **CustomerName** field in Edit mode. But i cant able to to pass the CustomerName related ContactPerson to **ContactPersom** dropdown in edit mode. I tries to explain my issue . Please any one help me to resolve this.

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by changing your view model to include a property for the `CustomerContact` objects associated with the `CustomerContactID` for use in your dropdownlist.

```
public class VisitorsViewModel
{
    ....
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a customer contact")]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Person")]
    public Nullable<System.Guid> CustomerContactID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CustomerContactList { get; set; } // add this
    .... // add other SelectLists rather than using ViewBag
}
```

Note you should also add similar `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` properties for Employees, POVisits and Items to avoid using `ViewBag`.

Next modify the GET method to populate the options for `CustomerContactID`

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
{
    WafeERP_NEWEntities db = new WafeERP_NEWEntities();
    View_VisitorsForm model = db.View_VisitorsForm.Find(id);

    VisitorsViewModel viewModel = new VisitorsViewModel()
    {
        VisitingID = model.VisitingID,
        ....
        // Add the following
        CustomerContactID = model.CustomerContactID,
        CustomerContactList = db.CustomerContacts.Where(x => x.CustomerID == model.CustomerContactID).Select(x => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = CustomerContactID,
            Text = ContactReference
        },
        .... // add the other select lists
    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And then in the view, use

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CustomerContactID", new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerContactID, Model.CustomerContactList, "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @class = "form-control })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CustomerContactID)
```

Note that you do not need attributes for `id` and `type` - they are already added by the `DropDownListFor()` method, and you should not have a `required` attribute which is HTML5 validation. Instead add a `[Required]` attribute and use `ValidationMessageFor()` so that you get server and client side validation.

Side note: If this were a create view, then you would assign the `CustomerContactList` options using

```
CustomerContactList = Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()
```

so that you initially display an empty dropdownlist.